# Remove instance of interface class in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Edit: Achieved partial solution by unsubscribing from event.

I had multiple instances of a List `PROBLEM` being called after starting several games. Unsubscribing from the event between calls solves this problem, however I am unable to Destroy `RunningGame` so I cannot be sure that I don't have many instances of each `GameType#` running.

How can I Destroy or check the instance count?

Turning all `GameType#`'s to static classes or Destroying `GameTypeManager` seem like improper solutions to the problem.

(I distilled my code to what I believe to be the problem, but I can post it in it's completion if it would be helpful).

```
public interface IGameType
{
    void CheckGameOver(PlayerState deadPlayer);
}

public class GameType0 : GameTypeManager, IGameType
{
    public List<int> PROBLEM = new List<int>();

    // code which terminates game (including CheckGameOver, as this implements the interface).
}
// Additional GameType#s

public class GameTypeManager : MonoBehavior
{
    public static IGameType RunningGame;

    public void Setup (int selectedGameType)
    {
        RunningGame = GetGameType(selectedGameType);
        EventManager.Killed += RunningGame.CheckGameOver;
    }

    public void TearDown ()
    {
        EventManager.Killed -= RunningGame.CheckGameOver;
    }

    // I am trying to implement the factory pattern here
    public IGameType GetGameType(int gameType)
    {
        IGameType currentGameType = null;
        switch (gameType)
        {
            case 0 :
                currentGameType = gameObject.AddComponent<GameType0>();
                break;
            // Additional cases...
        }
        return currentGameType;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by removing the reference to MonoBehavior `GameTypeManager`, thus allowing me to instantiate my class in a normal fashion and not worry about shuffling components around.

This is my solution code:

```
public class GameTypeManager
{
    public static IGameType RunningGame;

    public void Setup (int selectedGameType)
    {
        RunningGame = GetGameType(selectedGameType);
        EventManager.Killed += RunningGame.CheckGameOver;
    }

    public void TearDown ()
    {
        EventManager.Killed -= RunningGame.CheckGameOver;
        RunningGame = null;
    }

    public IGameType GetGameType(int gameType)
    {
        IGameType currentGameType = null;
        switch (gameType)
        {
            case 0 :
                currentGameType = new GameType0();
                break;
            // Additional cases...
        }
        return currentGameType;
    }
}

public interface IGameType
{
    void CheckGameOver(PlayerState deadPlayer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using same gameObject to add new instance of IGameType. Previous instance will remain in the memory as part of gameObject Component.

Try [`UnityEngine.Object.Destroy`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) function on gameObject. This function will remove the components of gameObject. Just call it for RunningGame after checking the GameOver. You can also specify the delay to destroy the gameObject instance.

> Update:

Use code like below:

```
 IMyComponent comp = obj.GetComponent<GameType1>() As IMyComponent;
 UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(gameToDestory);
```

Here you can not specify the Interface IGameType to GetComponents because it only accepts the Concrete types.

Comment: So use it to Destroy GameTypeManager?  It won't let me destroy RunningGame because it's not of type `GameObject`, and I can't cast it thusly.

Comment: So in your example is `IMyComponent` a stand-in for `IGameType`?  I tried code like that and I'm still getting a type error in Destroy

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you would need to store a reference to both the MonoBehaviour and the Interface. Then anytime you use the Interface object you need to check that the monobeahiour reference != null.  Unity overrides the != operator and knows when you destroy the object.  It doesn't however have the ability to override the != operator for the interface and therefore when you destroy the mono behaviour the Interface wont be null but will still throw an error.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I was looking for an option which didn't require destruction of the monobehavior class though.  That does make sense though, thank you.